# Installing OpenCV on Node problems

Tags: node.js, npm

I have installed all the dependencies and have all compilers installed etc. Then when I finally try to install OpenCv in Node.js with Node Package Manager, I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
gyp: Call to 'pkg-config --cflags opencv' returned exit status 127. while trying to load bind
```

Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: Install `pkg-config` on your system then. For Ubuntu, `sudo apt-get install pkg-config`.

Comment: @bnuhero - I have done this, but through Mac ports instead, yet still get the same error.

Comment: Run `which pkg-config` to find where `pkg-config` is installed.